# Executable File IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER ImageBase is 0

Tags: c, 64-bit, header-files

I've encountered a problem I am trying to figure out for a while now but I am unable to find anything about it, I am trying to get a mapped file image base from its optional header found in the PE header but the value in the ImageBase is 0?

The file I am trying to get this value from is a 64 bit executable (PE64), so what I am doing is I open the file with (CreateFileW function), then I map it using (CreateFileMappingW and MapViewOfFile functions), then I get the PE Header file with these functions:

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* FileUtils_GetFileDOSHeader (void* Arg_FileViewMap) {
        if (Arg_FileViewMap != NULL) {
                return (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*) Arg_FileViewMap;
        }
        return NULL;
}

IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* FileUtils_GetFilePEHeader (void* Arg_FileViewMap) {
        if (Arg_FileViewMap != NULL) {
                IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* Func_FileDOSHeader = FileUtils_GetFileDOSHeader(Arg_FileViewMap);
                if (Func_FileDOSHeader != NULL) {
                        return (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*) ((INT64) Func_FileDOSHeader + Func_FileDOSHeader->e_lfanew);
                }
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

Then I use this function to get the optional header or do it directly, same result:

```
IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER* FileUtils_GetFileOptionalHeader (void* Arg_FileViewMap) {
        if (Arg_FileViewMap != NULL) {
                IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* Arg_FilePEHeader = FileUtils_GetFilePEHeader(Arg_FileViewMap);
                if (Arg_FilePEHeader != NULL) {
                        return (IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER*) &Arg_FilePEHeader->OptionalHeader;
                }
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

Then I try to get value and print it out so I would know that its not 0 like so:

```
wprintf(L"File image base: 0x%015X\n", FileUtils_GetFileOptionalHeader(Func_TargetFileViewMap)->ImageBase);
```

That is all! Once I compile this code for 64bit and run it, it prints out 0 but it should give me 0x00000010000000, so what is wrong here? The value does print out correctly, I made sure that the value is indeed 0 a lot of times.

Now things to note:

1. Some executables do give me the ImageBase value, but most of them give me 0 even though that is wrong, for example I open notepad and that gives me 0 but the value should be 0x00000010000000, and to show you that here is a screenshot of what CFF Explorer sees: [(http://prntscr.com/) <- Click](http://prntscr.com/js6ney)
2. It appears that all other values are correct except the ImageBase that is 0 for some reason, if I print out the EntryPoint then the value does match with what the CFF Explorer tells me.
3. I am using GCC (From MinGW-w64) compiler (C Programming Language) for this
4. I am not aware of any other invalid values in other headers, its just the ImageBase getting me frustrated.

A quick thing, if you also need to know what the function parameters for opening and mapping the file are then here they are:

```
HANDLE Func_TargetFile = CreateFileW((wchar_t*) & Func_ConsoleCommand, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
HANDLE Func_TargetFileMapping = CreateFileMappingW(Func_TargetFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, NULL);
void* Func_TargetFileViewMap = MapViewOfFile(Func_TargetFileMapping, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
```

That is all, once again if you are confused of what my question is: Why does the IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER ImageBase gives me a value of 0 even though all other values in the header seem to match what CFF Explorer shows me? - Thank you

PS: I will check consistently, if you need more information then comment below.

Comment: Alright, if I set the ImageBase to 10000000 then it prints out: Image base: 0x000000005F5E100 instead of 0 and when converted to decimal the value is correct. If I do a IF statement check if the ImageBase is 0 it does return true, just to confirm it once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the mistery, it was in the GetFilePEHeader function! The printed out value is now: 0x000000005F5E100

The issue was with the casting, this line of code:

```
return (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*) ((char*) (Func_FileDOSHeader) + Func_FileDOSHeader->e_lfanew);
```

Here is the fixed function:

```
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* FileUtils_GetFilePEHeader (void* Arg_FileViewMap) {
        if (Arg_FileViewMap != NULL) {
                IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* Func_FileDOSHeader = FileUtils_GetFileDOSHeader(Arg_FileViewMap);
                if (Func_FileDOSHeader != NULL) {
                        return (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*) ((INT64) Func_FileDOSHeader + Func_FileDOSHeader->e_lfanew);
                }
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

Thank you all for all of your help, this was quite a dumb issue. It took me 3 days to figure this out.